# Numerically solving a partial differential equation in python with Runge Kutta 4

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, python, runge-kutta-methods, finite-difference-methods

I'm supposed to solve the following partial differential equation in python using Runge-Kutta 4 method in time.

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}v(y,t)=Lv(t,y)
$$

where $L$ is the following linear operator

$$
L=\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}-\alpha^2\right)^{-1}\left\{-i\alpha(1-y^2)\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}-\alpha^2\right)-2i\alpha+\frac{1}{R}\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}-\alpha^2\right)^2\right\}
$$

The spatial dimension is discretized along the $N = 101$ grid points from $y = -1$ to $y = 1$.

The boundary conditions are `v[0] = 0` and `v[N-1] = 0` and

$$
\left.\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right|_{y=-1}=\left.\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right|_{y=1}=0
$$

I have to discretize the second- and fourth-derivative operators using central finite difference and create a function for them. Using those functions, I can then create the $L$ operator.

Finally, using the initial condition $v(y) = 0.02(1+\cos(\pi y))$ time step $dt= 0.01$ and parameter values $R=500$ and $\alpha=0.3$, I have to find $v$ after 10s.

I have written the following code where the $L$ operator is put in a matrix form. The first few iterations seem to work giving somewhat reasonable results but then the values explode and I get an error. I'm not sure where the problem is, I might be misunderstanding how to implement the problem.

Another point I'm unsure about is whether the inverse of the $\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}-\alpha^2\right)$ operator can be understood as the inverse of the matrix representation of that operator or if that's not the case.

Can anybody give me some pointers as to how to solve this?

```
import numpy 
import scipy
from scipy import linalg
from matplotlib import pyplot
%matplotlib inline

N=101
L=1.0

#creating the grid points
y=numpy.linspace(-L+0.04,L-0.04,N-4)
dy=(2*L)/(N-1)

v=numpy.empty(N-4)

# Operator of the second derivative acting on v with respect to y 
def D2_v(N,dy):

    # Setup the diagonal of the operator.
    D = numpy.diag((-2.0/ (dy**2)) * numpy.ones(N-4))

    # Setup the upper diagonal of the operator.
    U = numpy.diag((1.0/ (dy**2)) * numpy.ones(N - 5), k=1)
    # Setup the lower diagonal of the operator.
    L = numpy.diag((1.0/ (dy**2)) * numpy.ones(N - 5), k=-1)
    # Assemble the operator.
    D2_v = D + U + L
    # Setup the Neumann condition 
    D[-1, -1] = (-7.0/4.0) / (dy**2)
    D[0, 0] = (-7.0/4.0) / (dy**2)

    return D2_v

# Operator of the fourth derivative acting on v with respect to y 
def D4_v(N,dy):

    # Setup the diagonal of the operator.
    D = numpy.diag((6.0/ (dy**4)) * numpy.ones(N-4))

    # Setup the upper diagonal of the operator.
    U = numpy.diag((-4.0/ (dy**4)) * numpy.ones(N - 5), k=1)
    U2 = numpy.diag((1.0/ (dy**4)) * numpy.ones(N - 6), k=2)

    # Setup the lower diagonal of the operator.
    L = numpy.diag((-4.0/ (dy**4)) * numpy.ones(N - 5), k=-1)
    L2 = numpy.diag((1.0/ (dy**4)) * numpy.ones(N - 6), k=-2)

    # Assemble the operator.
    D4 = D + U + L + U2 + L2

    # Setup the Neumann condition 
    D4[-1, -1] = (5.0) / (dy**4)
    D4[0, 0] = (5.0) / (dy**4)
    D4[1, 0] = (-7.0/4.0) / (dy**4)
    D4[-2, -1] = (-7.0/4.0) / (dy**4)

    return D4

D2=D2_v(N,dy)
D4=D4_v(N,dy)   

# Operator L
def L_v(N,y,dy,R,alpha):

    Ma = alpha*numpy.identity(N-4)
    My = numpy.diag(y)
    I = numpy.identity(N-4)
    Lv = numpy.linalg.inv(D2-Ma**2)*(-1j*Ma*(I-My**2)*(D2-Ma**2)+1j* 
     (-2.0)*Ma+(1.0/R)*(D4-D2*(Ma**2)-(Ma**2)*D2+(Ma**4)))

    return Lv    

#parameters
alpha=0.3
R=500.0
dt=0.01

L1=L_v(N,y,dy,R,alpha)

#initial value for v
for i in range(N-4):    
    v[i]=0.02*(1.0+numpy.cos(numpy.pi*y[i]))

#Runge Kutta implementation for 1000 time steps
for m in range(1000):

    k1 = dt*numpy.matmul(L1,v)
    k2 = dt*numpy.matmul(L1,v + 0.5*k1)
    k3 = dt*numpy.matmul(L1,v + 0.5*k2)
    k4 = dt*numpy.matmul(L1,v + k3)

    v = v + (1.0/6.0)*(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)
```

Comment: To be honest, I haven't looked through your code, nor whether the PDE is even well posed, but a suggestion. It is more numerically stable to write the PDE as a system, perhaps like $$\partial_{t} u = -i \alpha (1-y^{2})u - 2 i \alpha v + R^{-1} (\partial_{y}^{2} - \alpha) u, \quad (\partial_{y}^{2} - \alpha) v = u$$ Also, dividing by a number is _never_ a good idea, even if that number is not too small, because the elements of the matrix you are multiplying it against might be quite small and so the matrix might become close to singular, so perhaps multiply through the first equation by $R$.

Comment: You might also want to check the accuracy of the stencil you are using, whether a CFL condition is required etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sadly this being for and assignment I have to treat the equation as such and the stencil is given as it is. My main problem right now is actually how to interpret the inverse differential operator, the first term in L.

Comment: Well once discretised, the operator $\partial_{y}^{2} - \alpha$ becomes a matrix, we'll call $M$, so really you are solving $$\partial_{t} M v = -i \alpha (1 - \tilde{y}^{2}) M v - 2 i \alpha v + R^{-1} M M v$$ where the tilde represents the discretisation of $y$. Does that help?

Comment: And what would be the inverse of the matrix representation of that operator ? considering I have to use the differential eq. as stated in the question I have to find some matrix representation of the inverse operator, shouldn't it be some sort of integral?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite understanding the issue. By discretising the operator $\partial_{y}^{2} - \alpha$, you've turned it into a matrix $M$. Hence, calling the RHS $f(Mv)$, you have $$\partial_{t} Mv = f(Mv) \implies \partial_{t} v = M^{-1} f(Mv)$$ where $M^{-1}$ is the matrix inverse of $M$ such that $M M^{-1} = I$, $I$ the identity matrix.

Comment: That's what I originally did but I guess I'm not quite sure if the inverse operator is just the inverse of the matrix representation of that operator